# springmvc project( not spring boot) wrant to make use of auto configuration ablility, what should I do

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a old project, base on spring mvc. I don't wrant to transform it to spring boot project beause of too much work.

but I wrant to make use of auto configuration ability which like spring boot.

what shoud I do?

Comment: Use Spring Boot. Anything else will lead to implement what Spring Boot does.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you include in "auto configuration"?